# Website does not auto resize even with width: 100%;?

Tags: html, css

i seem to have a bit of a problem. I've set the table to 100% for the width attribute, but the window stays the same at 1600. How do i go about making the webpage fit into my browser? (Lets say my browser's width is 1024.)

Also, ignore the main.css. It only has a background attribute on it.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table width="100%" height="1200" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="page">
<tr>
    <td colspan="17">
        <img src="images/index_01.png" width="1600" height="39" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="39" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="10">
        <img src="images/index_02.png" width="57" height="1161" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="5" rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/indexpic_01.png" width="668" height="177" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="11">
        <img src="images/index_04.png" width="875" height="154" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="154" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="9" rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/index_05.png" width="539" height="44" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/indexpic_02.png" width="189" height="44" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="9">
        <img src="images/index_07.png" width="147" height="1007" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="23" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        <img src="images/index_08.png" width="668" height="21" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="21" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="7">
        <img src="images/index_09.png" width="94" height="963" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="14">
        <img src="images/indexpic_11.png" width="1302" height="480" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="480" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="14">
        <img src="images/index_11.png" width="1302" height="24" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="24" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/index_12.png" width="291" height="60" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/index_13.png" width="46" height="459" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="images/index_14.png" width="291" height="60" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
        <img src="images/index_15.png" width="46" height="411" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="4">
        <img src="images/index_16.png" width="291" height="60" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/index_17.png" width="46" height="459" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="images/index_18.png" width="291" height="60" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="60" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/indexpic_05.png" width="291" height="320" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="images/indexpic_06.png" width="291" height="320" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="4">
        <img src="images/indexpic_07.png" width="291" height="320" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="images/indexpic_08.png" width="291" height="320" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="320" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="images/index_23.png" width="291" height="79" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="images/index_24.png" width="291" height="31" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="4">
        <img src="images/index_25.png" width="291" height="31" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
        <img src="images/index_26.png" width="291" height="79" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="31" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/index_27.png" width="78" height="48" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="images/indexpic_09.png" width="213" height="31" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/index_29.png" width="29" height="48" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="images/indexpic_10.png" width="109" height="31" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/indexpic_12.png" width="17" height="31" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/indexpic_13.png" width="97" height="31" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/index_33.png" width="85" height="48" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="31" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="images/index_34.png" width="213" height="17" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="4">
        <img src="images/index_35.png" width="223" height="17" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="17" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="57" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="94" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="291" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="46" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="78" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="159" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="54" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="29" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="17" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="92" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="17" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="97" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="85" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="46" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="102" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="189" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="147" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Comment: It is because you are stuffing a 1600px wide image inside your table.  I do not recommend using tables for layout.

Comment: I have to be honest, I cried a little when I saw your code. No CSS, table based design, and images instead of content. This looks like code straight out of 1998.

Comment: I last used Dreamweaver in secondary school. Those were the days.

Comment: How old is this code? It looks like HTML 3.2! (Except it's not _valid_ HTML 3.2, but that's OK, the validator wasn't around in those days.) Anyway, to answer the question, `width` on tables is usually interpreted as "it would be nice to have this width if possible; ignore otherwise". That's the difference between tables and most other elements.

Comment: and what should i do? i tried removing the width attribute for all of the images inside the table but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not doing a website. i'm editing something else. Explains why i don't have any text.

Comment: What do you _want_ to do? Should the images shrink if the user makes the window smaller?

Comment: I want the table to fit a standard webpage, that's all. Say if the browser's size is 1024 x 768 and my original size of the table is 1600 x 1200, i want it to autosize the width to fit 1024 instead.

Comment: @RenoYeo As I state in my answer, try converting the width to percentages and that will make everything resize. It won't look very pretty but it will accomplish it.

Comment: Do you want the images to scale down?

Comment: all of the images? yes, in according to the browser size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your image widths are set explicitly, and they add up to `1601px`, which would stretch your table (and page) to fit.

Here's my recommendation: Ditch the images and try to do you layout with actual content (and elements other than tables). You can't very easily dynamically size this width as it stands now.

If you are dead set on this (and I cringe at the thought) you can convert the pixel widths of all the images into percentage width, and, while you'll have issues with rounding, you should get a resized layout based on width. But it won't look pretty.

Comment: And to prevent the images being blown up when the width is larger, you can set both the width in pixels and a max-width in percents.

Comment: elements? you mean use <div>s instead of <table>s?

Comment: @RenoYeo Yes. Try to accomplish your layout using more semantic elements (and `<div>`s, which are still more semantically appropriate than `<table>`s). Also, be sure to include a `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of you page so that it renders in standards mode. And you should use CSS to style your elements instead of tables. [Google](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/) has good tutorials and so does [SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css).

Answer (score 0):

Your row widths adds up to more than 1024, so you wont be able to set it to 100%.
The browser picks up the highest of the width in % and the total width of your `<td>`s.